# Reinitializing variables in R and having them update globally

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I'm not sure how to pose this question with the right lingo and the related questions weren't about the same thing. I wanted to plot a function and noticed that R wasn't udpating the plot with my change in a coefficient.

```
a <- 2
x <- seq(-1, 1, by=0.1)
y <- 1/(1+exp(-a*x))
plot(x,y)

a <- 4
plot(x,y) # no change

y <- 1/(1+exp(-a*x)) # redefine function
plot(x,y) # now it updates
```

Just in case I didn't know what I was doing, I followed the syntax on [this R basic plotting tutorial](http://msenux.redwoods.edu/math/R/simple.php). The only difference was the use of `=` instead of `<-` for assignment of `y = 1/(1+exp(-a*x))`. The result was the same.

I've actually never just plotted a function with R, so this was the first time I experienced this. It makes me wonder if I've seen bad results in other areas if re-defined variables aren't propagated to functions or objects initialized with the initial value.

1) Am I doing something wrong and there is a way to have variables sort of dynamically assigned so that functions take into account the current value vs. the value it had when they were created?

2) If not, is there a common way R programmers work around this when tweaking variable assignments and making sure everything else is properly updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not, in fact, plotting a function. Instead, you are plotting two vectors. Since you haven't updated the values of the vector before calling the next plot, you get two identical plots.

To plot a function directly, you need to use the `curve()` function:

```
f <- function(x, a)1/(1+exp(-a*x))
```

Plot:

```
curve(f(x, 1), -1, 1, 100)
```

[image]

```
curve(f(x, 4), -1, 1, 100)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Both your answer and DWin's say the same thing, but you explained things better. I looked into `curve()` and think I understand now... and feel silly for asking this.

Answer (score 1):

R is not Excel, or MathCAD, or any other application that might lead you to believe that changing an object's value might update other vectors that might have have used that value at some time in the past. When you did this

```
a <- 4
plot(x,y) # no change
```

There was no change in 'x' or 'y'.

Try this:

```
curve( 1/(1+exp(-a*x))  )
a <- 10
curve( 1/(1+exp(-a*x)) )
```

Comment: Yup, this was my problem... I looked at `y` and realized it's just a vector created based on whatever `x` was. Now it makes sense that plotting `x` vs. `y` just creates a simple plot based on two vectors and uses whatever `y` was at the time it was created.